# Embedding SVGs into PDFs with embedded fonts

Tags: pdf, svg, fonts, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I want to embed an SVG image into a PDF, and have the font families specified in the SVG `text` elements render using the correct fonts.

The fonts I am using are the ['Lato' TTF fonts](http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/).

Here is the code I have used to convert the fonts to TCPDF's "native format":

```
$variants = [
    'Black',
    'BlackItalic',
    'Bold',
    'BoldItalic',
    'Hairline',
    'HairlineItalic',
    'Heavy',
    'HeavyItalic',
    'Italic',
    'Light',
    'LightItalic',
    'Medium',
    'MediumItalic',
    'Regular',
    'Semibold',
    'SemiboldItalic',
    'Thin',
    'ThinItalic',
];

foreach ($variants as $variant) {
    \TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(
        '/var/www/fonts/Lato-' . $variant . '.ttf',
        '',
        '',
        32,
        '/var/www/fonts/output/'
    );
}
```

And here is the code I've used to generate a test PDF with an embedded SVG:

```
$svg_content = '<svg width="600px" height="800px">';
foreach ($variants as $key => $variant) {
    $svg_content .= '<text x="30" y="' . ( 30 * ( $key + 1 ) ) . '" fill="#ED6E46" font-size="20" font-family="\'Lato-' . $variant . '\'" text-anchor="start">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog (' . $variant . ').</text>';
}
$svg_content .= '</svg>';

$pdf = new TCPDF();

$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, -1, true);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->AddFont('Lato-Black', '', '/var/www/fonts/output/latoblack.php');

$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $svg_content, 0, 0, 300, 300, '', $align='', $palign='C', $border=0, false);

$pdf->Output(
    preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $influencer->getName()) . '.pdf',
    'I'
);
```

The result I get is that all the text is rendered in what I assume is Helvetica:

[image: Lato fonts not applied!]

If I add a line just before the call to `ImageSVG()` like this:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Lato-Black', '', null, '/var/www/fonts/output/latoblack.php');
```

Then all the text is rendered in Lato-Black:

[image: All text rendered in Lato-Black]

It seems to me that the fonts are being embedded in the PDF fine, but the `SetFont` obviously sets the current font for subsequent PDF text elements, and the `text` elements within the SVG image render using this font.

My desired behaviour is that the `font-family` attributes defined on the SVG `text` elements are honoured within the PDF, so that each line renders using the font variant mentioned in the brackets at the end of the line.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just because the file is called "Lato-BoldItalic", it doesn't mean that is how you should reference it in the SVG.

Have you tried just using `font-family="Lato"`?  If that works as I suspect, you can then produce all your variations using the normal way in CSS - `font-weight` and `font-style`.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it. It doesn't seem to make any difference - the font only changes when I call the TCPDF `SetFont()` method outside the SVG context. I am wondering if maybe I'm missing a step somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with the following code and work backwards incorporating your changes.

To be clear I'm not specifically advocating this as the way to do it, only that this is one way that works and so should help as a starting point.

**Font Converter:**

```
$variants = [
    'Black',
    'BlackItalic',
    'Bold',
    'BoldItalic',
    'Hairline',
    'HairlineItalic',
    'Heavy',
    'HeavyItalic',
    'Italic',
    'Light',
    'LightItalic',
    'Medium',
    'MediumItalic',
    'Regular',
    'Semibold',
    'SemiboldItalic',
    'Thin',
    'ThinItalic',
];

foreach ($variants as $variant) {
    \TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(dirname(__FILE__) . '/fonts/Lato-' . $variant . '.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
}

echo 'Done!';
```

This puts the `.php`, `.z` and `.ctg.z` files within `/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts`.

**PDF Generator:**

Note the different `font-family` names in the `$variants` array:

```
$variants = [
    'lato',
    'latob',
    'latobi',
    'latoblack',
    'latoblacki',
    'latohairline',
    'latohairlinei',
    'latoheavy',
    'latoheavyi',
    'latoi',
    'latolight',
    'latolighti',
    'latomedium',
    'latomediumi',
    'latosemib',
    'latosemibi',
    'latothin',
    'latothini'
];

$svg_content = '<svg width="600px" height="800px">';

foreach ($variants as $key => $variant) {
    $svg_content .= '<text x="30" y="' . ( 30 * ( $key + 1 ) ) . '" fill="#ED6E46" font-size="20" font-family="\'' . $variant . '\'" text-anchor="start">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog (' . $variant . ').</text>';
}

$svg_content .= '</svg>';

ob_start();

$pdf = new TCPDF();

$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, -1, true);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

$pdf->AddPage();
//$pdf->AddFont('latoblack', '', dirname(__FILE__) . '/fonts/output/latoblack.php');

$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $svg_content, 0, 0, 300, 300, '', $align='', $palign='C', $border=0, false);

$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've been able to generate a PDF that renders the fonts correctly now. Having read your answer, my main issue was to do with having my fonts in a custom directory. Once I had this corrected, I actually found that using variant names like `'Lato-Black'` does work - apart from `'Lato-Semibold'`, which causes the error: `TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: latosemi`. I'm not sure why it's looking for a file called `latosemi` - there are no references to it that I can see. Any ideas why?

Comment: Not sure, but `latosemi` should be `latosemib`. Sounds like a typo somewhere. `latosemib` didn't produce any errors for me